# Laravel 4.2 Mandrill Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mandrill

I really have no idea what the issue is, but there are no errors in the log... nothing is happening. Here's my configuration:

In app/config/mail.php

```
return array(

    'driver' => 'mandrill',

    'host' => 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',

    'port' => 587,

    'from' => array('address' => null, 'name' => null),

    'encryption' => 'tls',

    'username' => 'myemail@mydomain.com',

    'password' => 'my_api_key',

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'pretend' => false,

);
```

In app/config/services.php

```
return array(

    'mailgun' => array(
        'domain' => '',
        'secret' => '',
    ),

    'mandrill' => array(
        'secret' => 'my_api_key',
    ),

    'stripe' => array(
        'model'  => 'User',
        'secret' => '',
    ),

);
```

Comment: Can you set the driver to `smtp` and see if its working that way? Also may want to put a from email address just to eliminate that.. not sure if that does or does not have a baring

Comment: If changed to "SMTP", it fails with the following error: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username

Comment: That would lead me to check my credentials with mandrill and make sure you're authorized to send.

Comment: The Mandrill API logs really helped, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Laravel's documentation is a bit sparse ... I needed to include a "from" line in my `send` function:

```
$message->from('no-reply@mydomain.com', 'My Domain Sender');
```